# Changing some words in a string for highlight (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php

I can run JS Code smoothly but unfortunately, I could not do the same in PHP. I want to change some terms in the text for highlight. How can I do that?

```js
 var words = 'word1#word2#word3';
    var string = 'hello world, this is a word1, word2 and word3';
    
    words.split("#").map(w => {
      var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + w + '\\b', 'gi');
      string = string.replace(regex, `<span class="highlight">${w}</span>`);
    });

    console.log(string);
```

PHP code:

```
$words = 'word1#word2#word3';
$string = "hello world, this is a word1, word2 and word3";
$parts = explode('#', $words);
preg_match_all('\\b' + w + '\\b', 'gi', $string, $parts);
$result = array_combine($parts[1], $parts[2]);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `explode` to create an array of patterns called `$highlights`, to match the words that it exploded by space too, then i do a loop `foreach` over a `$words` and check if it match any of highlights words by using `in_array` if so  will highlight it by using `span` tag colored with red, otherwise it return it as it is.

```php
<?php
$highlights = 'word1#word2#word3';
$pieces = explode('#', $highlights);

$sentence = "hello world, this sentence contains some word should be highlighted a word1 and word2 and word3";
$words = explode(' ', $sentence);

$highlighted = '';
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if(in_array($word, $pieces))
        $highlighted .= "<span style='color:red;'>$word</span> ";
    else
        $highlighted .= $word." ";
}

echo $highlighted;
?>
```

Comment: Please, remember that you're writing for future readers as well. Code-only answers aren't often helpful to others. It would be great if you added some explanation of why you think your code solves the problem.

Comment: the code is work as question require and i just added some comments to clarify that it has more approach to achieve what need!

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: thank you so much Steven for note i will take it in consideration, also i will check the post out. and apply their notes.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Steverst1

Comment: it's my pleasure to help @Emre7

Answer (score 0):

1. In PHP, you could use:
   [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace)

> Perform a regular expression search and replace.

It performs a **global** sort of *replace* operation by default. Hence no need for a *global* `g` pattern modifier.

2. For a **case-insensitive** match, `i` pattern modifier is available as well.

[Pattern Modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

> i (PCRE_CASELESS) If this modifier is set, letters in the pattern
> match both upper and lower case letters.

3. For a **word boundary** match, PHP also provides the `\b` pattern modifier as well.
   *Reference:* [Example #2 Find the word "web"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Which boils down to the solution below:

```php
$words = "word1#word2#word3";
$string = "hello world, this is a word1, word2 and word3";

array_map(function ($w) use (&$string) {

    $string = preg_replace("/\b" . $w . "\b/i", "<span class='highlight'>$w</span>", $string);

}, explode("#", $words));

echo $string;
```

4. *More resources:*
   [Pattern Syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)